# Parametric copulas with marginals that are regressions

Tags: regression, copula, multivariate-distribution, parametric

In *Dependence Modeling with Copulas* (Harry Joe) I'm struggling to interpret the meaning of a statement. In Chaper 5.1, it is stated:

> **Parametric inference for copulas**
>
> For dependence modeling with copulas, most common is the use of parametric copula families. Advantages of parametric inference methods for copula models are the following.
>
> - They are easier to numerically implement than non-parametric approaches.
> - They can be used in high dimensions.
> - With the use of the likelihood, it is the same theory for continuous, discrete or mixed response variables, and censored or missing data can be accommodated.
> - They can be adapted to univariate margins that are regressions or time series models, or to time-varying dependence. Covariates can be included in univariate or dependence parameters.
> - They can easily be used to compare competing models.

My question relates to the fourth point, specifically to *They can be adapted to univariate margins that are regression*. It seems to imply that the copula specification **requires** some additional parameterisation due to the fact that the marginals are now regressions, dependent on covariates.

Intuitively, I can appreciate this as the covariates would determine the actual distribution of the marginals and therefore the copula would then also need to respond to this. However, I can also intuit that the copula has already been estimated using data from the marginal regressions and so already captures this information from the covariates.

That is, the $(u,v)$ used to estimate the copula already reflect the covariates from those marginal distributions. Is it ok for the copula specification to then be agnostic of those covariates?

Comment: In both "regression" and "time series model" settings, a collection of errors (or "innovations") is modeled as a random vector.  That's really just a special example of the "used in high dimensions" application in the second bullet.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @whuber. My question relates to the fourth point. Was your comment related to that?

Comment: Yes, it was, as I had hoped the phrases in quotes indicated.

Comment: Maybe my question isn't worded clearly. My question revolves around the implication (by Joe) that something about changing from a static marginal (fixed distribution, not dependent on covariates) to a regression marginal changes the specification of the copula and requires adaptation.